# Pandas columns of lists, check if lists are intersecting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame, called `a`, that has the following structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'numbers_a': [[2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 4], [4, 6, 9]],
    'numbers_b': [[2, 1, 3], [10, 11], [4, 5, 7]]
})
df

| id | numbers_a | numbers_b |
|----|-----------|-----------|
| 1  | [2, 3, 5] | [2, 1, 3] |
| 2  | [1, 2, 4] | [10, 11]  |
| 3  | [4, 6, 9] | [4, 5, 7] |
```

I want to add a new column to this data frame, called `result`, that should be `TRUE` if any one value in `numbers_b` are in `numbers_a`. Therefore, the following should be the resultant data frame:

```
| id | numbers_a | numbers_b | result |
|----|-----------|-----------|--------|
| 1  | [2, 3, 5] | [2, 1, 3] | TRUE   |
| 2  | [1, 2, 4] | [10, 11]  | FALSE  |
| 3  | [4, 6, 9] | [4, 5, 7] | TRUE   |
```

I have tried to use the following code snippet, but I am getting FALSE for all values:

```
a['result'] = pd.DataFrame(a.numbers_b.tolist()).isin(a.numbers_a).any(1).astype(bool)
```

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try set intersection:

```
df['numbers_a'].map(set) & df['numbers_b'].map(set)

0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

This works well with the overloaded pandas boolean operators, although it isn't particularly performant.

---

Another method involves list comprehensions:

```
[set(a).intersection(b) for a, b in zip(df['numbers_a'], df['numbers_b'])]
# [True, False, True]

# To assign the result back
df['result'] = [
    set(a).intersection(b) for a, b in zip(df['numbers_a'], df['numbers_b'])]
```